# R gsub remove words in column y from words in column x

Tags: r, gsub

I'm trying to use gsub to remove words / text in column y that are in column x.

```
x = c("a","b","c")
y = c("asometext", "some, a b text", "c a text")
df = cbind(x,y)
df = data.frame(df)
df$y = gsub(df$x, "", df$y)
```

If I run the code above, it removes only the text from column x row 1 and not all the rows:

```
> df
  x             y
1 a      sometext
2 b some,  b text
3 c       c  text
```

I want the end result to be:

```
> df
  x             y
1 a      sometext
2 b      some,   text
3 c      text
```

So all the words / letters from column x should be removed from the column y. Is this possible with gsub?

Comment: `df$y <- mapply(gsub, df$x, "", df$y)` can work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally `gsub` takes three arguments 1) pattern, 2) replacement and 3) vector to replace values.

The pattern must be a single string. And the same for the replacement. The only part of the function that is open to multiple values is the vector. We call it vectorized because of this.

```
gsub(df$x, "", df$y)  #doesn't work because 'df$x' isn't one string
```

The pattern argument is not vectorized, but we can use `mapply` to complete the task.

**mapply and gsub (bffs)**

```
x = c("a","b","c")
y = c("asometext", "some, a b text", "c a text")
repl = ""

#We do
mapply(gsub, x, repl, y)

#On the inside
gsub(x[[1]], repl[[1]], y[[1]])
gsub(x[[2]], repl[[2]], y[[2]])
gsub(x[[3]], repl[[3]], y[[3]])
```

You may be asking, but I only have one `repl`, how does `repl[[2]]` and `repl[[3]]` work? The function noticed that for us and repeated 'repl' until it equaled the length of the others.

Comment: Hi thanks! this works, but it only removes the x from the same row, so if row number 2 in column y contains "b", and the row 1 in column x contains "b" then it won't be removed. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Try `gsub(paste(df$x, collapse ="|"), "", df$y)`

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is the best explanation I have ever seen on any R function, thanks! upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using str_remove_all:

```
library(stringr)    
x  = c("a","b","c")
y  = c("asometext", "some, a b text", "c a text")
df = cbind(x,y)
df = data.frame(df,stringsAsFactors = F)

# creating a format of "[abc]" to use in str_remove_all
comb_a = paste0("[",paste(df$x,collapse = ""),"]")

df$y = sapply(df$y, function(r) str_remove_all(r, comb_a) )
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i tried the above answers on a really large dataset, and found this code to work the best:

```
x = c("a","b","c")
y = c("asometext", "some, a b text", "c a text")

library(qdap)

z<- mgsub(x, "", y)
```

which gives the desired solution:

```
z: "sometext", "some,  text", "  text"
```

This is because mgsub function is a wrapper for gsub that takes a vector of search terms and a vector or single value of replacements, and i have found it to be more powerful than gsub, especially when working with big datasets. it accomplishes what gsub takes 2-3 lines of code to do.

while the above gsub(paste0) solution works well with very small datasets, i have found it returns error for large datasets.

note for Mac users: before installing qdap package, make sure you have java and pdk (oracle) softwares installed on your computer beforehand. otw you will run into errors when installing/trying to run qdap package since it is java based.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to implement with a for loop

```
output <- y
for (i in 1:3){
    output <- gsub(pattern = x[i],
                 replacement = "",
                 output)
}
print(output)
```

The result you will get:

```
    print(output)
[1] "sometext"     "some,   text" "  text"
```