# gsub multiple replacements and one pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a large list of names in Spanish. Some of them have special characters (accents) that I'm trying to deal with. Each time it has an accent I have the characters "-+". There is no way to know if the replacement is an "á" or "é" or "í" or "ó" or "ú" or "ñ", but only looking on each name.

I have something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('adri-+n','in-+s','mar-+a','-+scar','l-+cio','juli-+n','jos-+','sof-+a','crist-+bal','yajn-+'))
```

And I know the accents looking at the names:

```
c('adrián','inés','maría','óscar','lúcio','julián','josé','sofía','cristóbal','yajnú')
```

What I want to obtain is the corrected data frame with the proper letter without accent. Something like:

```
cdf <- data.frame(name = c('adrian','ines','maria','oscar','lucio','julian','jose','sofia','cristobal','yajnu'))
```

I have built a variable with the proper replacements according to each name (note the escaping character '\+'):

```
a <- 'adri-\\+n|juli-\\+n'
e <- 'in-\\+s|jos-'
i <- 'mar-\\+a|sof-\\+a'
o <- '-\\+scar|crist-\\+bal'
u <- 'l-\\+cio|yajn-\\+'

cdf <- df %>% 
mutate(a=ifelse(str_detect(name,a),'a',''), e=ifelse(str_detect(name,e),'e',''),
       i=ifelse(str_detect(name,i),'i',''), o=ifelse(str_detect(name,o),'o',''),
       u=ifelse(str_detect(name,u),'u',''),
       lett = str_c(a,e,i,o,u)) %>% 
  mutate(name = gsub('-\\+', lett, name))
```

But the last `mutate(name = gsub('-\\+', lett, name))` does not work because I can not use the character column `lett` to get **multiple replacements**. In fact I got a warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `name`.
i argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
i Input `name` is `gsub("-\\+", lett, name)`. 
2: In gsub("-\\+", lett, name) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

And the undesired result:

```
> cdf
        name a e i o u lett
1     adrian a            a
2       inas   e          e
3      maraa     i        i
4      ascar       o      o
5      lacio         u    u
6     julian a            a
7       josa   e          e
8      sofaa     i        i
9  cristabal       o      o
10     yajna         u    u
```

I also tried the **mgsub** package, but (from I know) it works only for vector to vector replacements (multiple to multiple), not one pattern and multiple replacements.

How can I get the desired result?

```
> cdf
        name a e i o u lett
1     adrian a            a
2       ines   e          e
3      maria     i        i
4      oscar       o      o
5      lucio         u    u
6     julian a            a
7       jose   e          e
8      sofia     i        i
9  cristobal       o      o
10     yajnu         u    u
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:**
I finally find the solution I was looking for with `mutate( name = unlist(Map(gsub, pattern = '-\\+', replacement = lett, name)) )`:

```
cdf <- df %>% 
  mutate(a=ifelse(str_detect(name,a),'a',''), e=ifelse(str_detect(name,e),'e',''),
         i=ifelse(str_detect(name,i),'i',''), o=ifelse(str_detect(name,o),'o',''),
         u=ifelse(str_detect(name,u),'u',''),
         lett = str_c(a,e,i,o,u)) %>% 
  mutate(name = unlist(Map(gsub, pattern = '-\\+', replacement = lett, name)) )
> cdf
        name a e i o u lett
1     adrian a            a
2       ines   e          e
3      maria     i        i
4      oscar       o      o
5      lucio         u    u
6     julian a            a
7       jose   e          e
8      sofia     i        i
9  cristobal       o      o
10     yajnu         u    u
```

Comment: There's a function to replace non ascii characters in the textclean package. It's probably more appropriate than gsub for this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `apply` family function that does what you are looking for, check out `mapply`.

It doesn't fit into the dplyr pipes so create a temporary table then use it:

```
df2 <- cdf %>% 
  mutate(a=ifelse(str_detect(name,a),'a',''), 
         e=ifelse(str_detect(name,e),'e',''),
         i=ifelse(str_detect(name,i),'i',''), 
         o=ifelse(str_detect(name,o),'o',''),
         u=ifelse(str_detect(name,u),'u',''),
         lett = str_c(a,e,i,o,u))

with(df2, mapply(function(x,y) gsub('-\\+', x, y), lett, name))
```

This is very similar to this question [R gsub remove words in column y from words in column x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049013/r-gsub-remove-words-in-column-y-from-words-in-column-x/41049318#41049318). To help others search for these types of questions we may mark this as a duplicate (it's not a knock against you)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated. But it returns: "adrin"      "ins"    "maria"    "oscar"     "lcio"    "julin"     "jose"    "sofia" "cristbal"     "yajn"

Comment: I found the solution with this code: mutate(name = unlist(Map(gsub, pattern = '-\\+', replacement = lett, name)) )

Comment: you may also consider that we have different language settings in our R sessions. I do not get that output `"adrian"      "ines"     "maria"     "oscar"`